# Excel function/Date Table - Defining week and period

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, powerpivot

Forgive me if this is a rookie question, however I'm kind of at a loss. I've been evaluating the PowerPivot tool for Excel, and one of the guides I came across with how to most effectively leverage it suggested that I should create a Date table. So I followed a guide that was posted on [Office Help](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Understand-and-create-date-tables-in-Power-Pivot-in-Excel-1c8b072e-9108-442f-8115-c72ba796d31e#__toc368990001), and the first few steps were easy. The issue I encountered came up when I had to define a custom week calendar.

The function that is posted,

> =INT(([date]-40356)/7)

doesn't actually work as I would expect. In this case, after I adjusted for either the day of the week to be either the beginning of a pay period or the beginning of a fiscal year, it generates negative numbers.

Further, I need to extend the functionality so that once it counts to a certain number (in the case of pay periods, 27), it starts over at 1. The issue I realize I would have is how I would define each of the date ranges for the pay periods, they start on Thursday and end two weeks later on Wednesday.

My issue is, I think also compounded by how much I have learned about the PowerPivot Add-In to begin with. Although so far it seems like it will accept most functions, there isn't really a direct cell reference to speak of.

The sheet I'm seeking to replace had a function embedded to count the pay periods

> =IF(A2<27,A2+1,1)

However in this case, they placed this formula in A3, so they were able to add the static value into A2. I do have control of the data being added, and not all columns need to be available to the end user, so clearly I could create a counter column or something along those lines. I'm just wondering what the most effective way to:
-Define the weeks without getting negative values would be?
-Take the weeks value (which seems to be important based on the link above) and define a Period value, for either a fiscal week number or a pay week number?

[Screenshot of the PowerPivot area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsPhJ.jpg)

Comment: Can you post a real example? Also, the 40356 in that formula needs to be adjusted, it's not clear whether you did that or not (which is how a real example would help). Finally, if you need to "start over" after reaching some number, think `=MOD()`.

Comment: So what have you figured out already?

Comment: Also have this one, for the old function: [Screenshot of the old workbook](http://imgur.com/GqvlZbL)

Comment: What I have figured out so far: I don't think the stated formula for calculating the Week number will work, since it will change for each yearly value. While it might start at 36611, it would change to calculate the second year with regards to what the [Date] value needed to be subtracted by. If not for leap years, I could add a column that had the day of year (as in how many days into the year the FY change occurs); which would be different...I guess I could try something dirty like wrapping statement in an IF function, but I don't know what the logic would be that could be used repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an Excel table to the Power Pivot model.  So I would add one that contains your A2 value on a single row (with a column heading row).  I would call it the "Parameters" table - you can extend it for other uses later.

Then in your other Power Pivot formulas you can refer to it, e.g.

`MAX('Parameters'[My Parameter])`

Then you can edit that cell, then refresh and it will flow into your calculations.